# Perl Mime::Lite hash of array derefrence

Tags: perl, hash, mime

I have a array of hash which I am dereferencing in the `msg->attach()` function of the `Mime::Lite`. The code is as follows:

```
for my $href (@$aref){
    $msg->attach(
            Type     => 'text',
            Data     => "productype: $href->{prodtype}   product: $href->{product}    qbs_id:$href->{qbs_id}\n";
    );
}
```

It indicates syntax error in the above example. Please inform me if this is a right way to put `msg->attach()` in a loop or we can't keep it in a loop. Thank you.

Comment: the dereferencing of `$href` at `qbs_id` is broken (at least in the posted code fragment).

Comment: I got confused with the editing part. Sorry for that. I have edited it. Please can you have a look once again.

Comment: heed the notice of amon: the argument list to the `attach` call still ends with a `;`, that is syntatically invalid!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the argument list for `attach`, no semicolons `;` may occur. Use a comma `,` to seperate the arguments:

```
for my $href (@$aref) {
    $msg->attach(
        Type => 'text',
        Data => "productype: $href->{prodtype}   product: $href->{product}    qbs_id:$href->{qbs_id}\n",
    );
}
```

A trailing comma may also be omitted, but I consider that bad style.

Comment: I have edited it once again. Please check. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Point taken. It works fine. But this comes as an attachment in the mail. I want it in the body of the email. Please can you suggest some advice. Thank you.

Comment: @deep The `attach` method is used to construct multipart messages. If you only want to send one part, then you should concatenate the strings first, and build the MIME::Lite object afterwards. (Also, MIME::Lite is deprecated according to its documentation).